# Submit form without reloading page through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Is there any way to submit the form to server for an AJAX response without reloading the page. I am able to do this with submit button. But how can I do that when a link is clicked.

I came to know about a javascript method to do this,

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
form.submit();
```

But the above code reloads the page. I came to know that we can do this with jquery but how?

Please Note that I am developing my application in Ruby on Rails 3.0.4 and I am using the rails AJAX like this.

```
<%= form_for @search, :remote => true, :url => request_path, :html => {:method => :get, :id => :my_form} do |f| %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should put the `event.preventDefault();` statement in your submit handler to prevent default page refresh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by just using this code. No need to define a function inside submit.

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Comment: The correct answer is the one from François Wahl, this one is simply wrong and the green check is misleading.
Can you move the green check?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method of `event` object :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
   $.ajax({
     ...
   });
})
```

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.post()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to do an ajax post.

Taken from the documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

You could also use [**.submit()**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Taken from documentation:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

> Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens
>   prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by
>   calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false
>   from our handler.

You can combine the 2 as shown by `Raminson`:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
    .preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Comment: Your second option is perfect for me. I just written a part of your provided solution i.e.
    `'$('#target').submit();`
don't know how but it just worked for me the way I wanted.

No need to call `.preventDefault().`

Answer (score 2):

I know i am a bit late to the party, as an alternative to the above anwsers, you could use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) for easy ajax form updating.

If you used it, the most simple version of your JS code would look like this.

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm(function() { 
  success: alert('success');
});
```

There are many more options you can use to configure it how you like.
The url that the form is submitted to is the same as the `action` attribute of your form.

This can also be changed.

From my exprecience you do not need to `preventDefault()` the submit either, it does it for you.

Anyways, this is another alternative to your problem, if you find it convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is your page reloading with form.submit() try:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
form.submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    //an ajax post as in François Wahl answer

});
```