# Resize page only once onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that calls a second page.  This page is simply to ask the user to answer a couple of questions so I am resizing the new page.

```
<body onLoad="moveTo(200,200); resizeTo(400,200);">
```

This works fine but after the user answers the questions I want to again resize the page to a larger size to show the answers.

```
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" onClick="resizeTo(800,800);" />
```

When the Go button is pressed it does resize to the larger page.  Unfortunately, after a couple of seconds it again resizes back to the size issued in the body tag.  How can I resize the page at different times without it reverting back to the body tags requirements?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your intention to refresh/navigate to a new page?

Comment: the resize in the input could be triggering the body onload again, due to having to reflow/reload parts of the page. I'd suggest putting a simple alert into the body onload to see if this is the case. if so, then set a sentinel variable to disable the body onload after it runs the first time.

Comment: @MarcB : I am not hijacking this thread, but just out of curiosity wanted to know : How can the body onload be disabled ?

Comment: @MarcB can body.onload be called more than once for a document without refresh or iframes? If so, under what conditions? (a link would sufice for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting a form reloads the page. To prevent this try this answer here: [Submit form without reloading page through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882444/submit-form-without-reloading-page-through-ajax) (the comment under the question also works)

Comment: I'm not sure if its ajax or not because I'm not familiar with it but I changed my submit input to a button input.  Then I used onClick="document.body.innerHTML='';" and it worked fine.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
t

Answer (score 0):

You could set the size the page has to be in a cookie before you submit this form and then read the cookie in the resizing of the page.